# Prevent passing unknown string literal but allow passing dynamic strings

Tags: typescript

Suppose we have the following TypeScript code:

```
const ages = {
    alice: 25,
    bob: 30,
    charlie: 35,
}

type PersonName = keyof typeof ages

function getAge<
    Name extends string,
    Ret = Name extends PersonName
        ? number
        : string extends Name
        ? (number | null)
        : null
>(name: Name): Ret {
    return (ages[name as PersonName] ?? null) as Ret
}
```

The conditional-type return value of `getAge` gives different types for the following 3 cases:

```
getAge('alice')                          // case 1, return type is `number`
getAge('frankie')                        // case 2, return type is `null`
getAge(prompt('Enter your name:') ?? '') // case 3, return type is `number | null`
```

What I want to do is *disallow* case 2 at compile time, such that only a known name *or* a dynamic string (determined at runtime) can be passed, but a literal name that's known not to exist fails to type-check.

Is this possible?

Comment: `... ?? ''` is a literal. And no, I don't see how this should be possible. A `string` is a `string` no matter how it is assigned or passed.

Comment: @Behemoth `''` is a literal; `{{something dynamic}} ?? ''` isn't (the `?? ''` path is only evaluated if the dynamic thing is null; `prompt(...)` returns null if the user cancels the operation). Clearly TypeScript is capable of distinguishing between a dynamic string and a literal string, otherwise it wouldn't be able to correctly distinguish the return types of cases 1 and 2 vs case 3 in my example. My question is whether it's _also_ able to restrict the function parameter in a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out — the parameter can also be given a conditional type of a similar shape:

```
const ages = {
    alice: 25,
    bob: 30,
    charlie: 35,
}

type PersonName = keyof typeof ages

function getAge<
    Name extends string,
    Ret = Name extends PersonName
        ? number
        : string extends Name
        ? (number | null)
        : never
>(name: Name extends PersonName
        ? Name
        : string extends Name
        ? Name
        : never
): Ret {
    return (ages[name as PersonName] ?? null) as Ret
}
```

```
getAge('alice') // OK, return type is `number`
getAge('frankie') // Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
getAge(prompt('Enter your name:') ?? '') // OK, return type is `number | null`
```